# MYSQL - Getting OK as a result, due to the subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My Workbench is giving me an "OK" as an output, without any further information.
Due to previous questions I found out that the problem is the subquery. But I don´t know what the problem is.

This is my Code:

```
**CREATE FUNCTION crew_headcount(FlightNo varchar(7), DepartureDateAndTimeUTC timestamp)
RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CASE
    WHEN  
        FlightNo IN(flightexecution.FlightNo) 
        AND DepartureDateAndTimeUTC IN(flightexecution.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC)
    THEN 
         (SELECT COUNT(crew.EmployeeID) 
         FROM crew, flightexecution 
         WHERE crew.FlightNo = flightexecution.FlightNo 
             AND FlightNo = flightexecution.FlightNo 
             AND DepartureDateAndTimeUTC = flightexecution.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC)
    ELSE -1 
    END;**
```

My goal is that I fill my function with the parameters FlightNO and DepatureTime and if these two values can be found in the available table, the number of crewmembers should come out as a result, otherwise a "-1".

Hope somebody can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Did you run the subquery by itself?

Comment: yes, and it works exactly like i want it to work

Comment: Not a MySQL person, but what is "OK" as a result? Like it's not giving you the COUNT it's literally just printing "OK"?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it would be returning "OK" other than the fact that the function executed without issue.  How are you running the function in MySQL Workbench? What version of Workbench?

You might try refactoring the WHEN portion of your CASE statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN  
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM flightexecution 
         WHERE flightexecution.FlightNo = FlightNo AND
               flightexecution.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC = DepartureDateAndTimeUTC) > 0
    THEN 
         (SELECT COUNT(crew.EmployeeID) 
         FROM crew, flightexecution 
         WHERE crew.FlightNo = flightexecution.FlightNo 
             AND FlightNo = flightexecution.FlightNo 
             AND DepartureDateAndTimeUTC = flightexecution.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC)
    ELSE -1 
END
```

Ultimately, this could be completely refactored into just a single SELECT statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(crew.EmployeeID) > 0 
            THEN COUNT(crew.EmployeeID) 
            ELSE -1 
       END AS Result
FROM crew
JOIN flightexecution ON crew.FlightNo = flightexecution.FlightNo
WHERE FlightNo = flightexecution.FlightNo AND 
      DepartureDateAndTimeUTC = flightexecution.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC
```

Comment: Dear Sean Murhpy, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: My pleasure @Jimbo.Koen - if my answer solved your problem, can you flag it as the correct answer and maybe give me an up-vote? :)  Thanks!